# TSQL Script To Extract Specific Parts of Word Document And Insert Into SQL Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-word

I have a word document with some text and images. I want to extract specific parts of the document and insert into columns in SQL table.

**Word Document Example**

```
House Name: House One
Townland: Townland One
```

I want something like if the title "House Name" is present, take the text that comes after it, in this case "House One" and insert that into the column in the table. Is there a library or a script I could use to do this. I have done a lot of internet searches but could not find anything similar to my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft PIA(Primary Interop Assemblies) or OpenXmlSDK .the following code is used to open Word Document And Reading All Texts using PIA (add reference via Visual Studio References and Choose Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Word.xx  ==> xx is version of PIA installed like 14.0 or 15.0 )

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var document=app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\srivastav_a\Desktop\TO WHOM SO EVER IT MAY CONCERN.docx");
        var text = document.Content.Text;

//do something
        app.Quit();
```

you may refer to following links 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcyt0y1f.aspx

OpenXML
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of TSQL like a script that would do this for me